# Open Graph tag for Whatsapp link sharing

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, social-media

I use Open Graph tags for sharing on social media. My image is 1200 x 630 pixels and works on Facebook and Whatsapp:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://emotionathletes.org/images/logo_1200x630_facebook_shared_image_EN.png">
```

On Facebook, the image appears OK, since it's made for it. On Whatsapp, the appears cropped, since seems to expect a square image.

Can I use a tag to provide an image for sharing only on Whatsapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify two (or more) Open Graph images, the first, rectangular image for FB and a second, square image for WhatsApp.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://emotionathletes.org/images/logo_1200x630_facebook_shared_image_EN.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://emotionathletes.org/images/logo_400x400_facebook_shared_image_EN.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
```

WhatsApp will use the last image.

Comment: Except, it doesn't (for me at least)