# What open graph preview image dimensions will universally display correctly?

Tags: html

We post our press releases on social media and also text a link to them for our subscribers.  We create an OG preview image of the recommended size for Facebook of 1200 x 630 pixels. It displays OK on Facebook, but the top gets cut off on Google Messages.  So we made a border of white space 120 pixels all the way around the image. Now I discover that WhatsApp truncates it to a square image. I saw on a webpage called the "Ultimate Guide to Open Graph Images" that they truncate their own OG previews to a square shape in a "you may also like" section of the page.  I do see that some platforms handle pretty much any size and aspect ratio. So what are the dimensions and visible area that work universally, or nearly universally?  If there aren't any, is there a way to target different images for different platforms?

I did see this post, but the OP says the answer given doesn't work.
[Open Graph tag for Whatsapp link sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329965/open-graph-tag-for-whatsapp-link-sharing)